# how create expandable list with different items

Tags: android, listview, github, expandablelistview

I used [this github project](https://github.com/aaironman/SlideExpandListView) but I want to add different sub list for each item of expandable list. what should i do?

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.single_expandable_list);
    ActionSlideExpandableListView list = (ActionSlideExpandableListView)this.findViewById(R.id.list);

    // fill the list with data
    list.setAdapter(buildDummyData());

    list.setItemActionListener(new OnActionClickListener() {...});
```

Comment: Create an issue on the project will bring more than asking there I guess

Comment: @LaurentMeyer don't understand u!!

Comment: StackOverflow is not the platform for that: the guy who created the lib you're using will very certainly be able to answer your questions. If I want to answer, I'll certainly need to understand the whole library project you're working with. So, open an issue on his Github project

Comment: @LaurentMeyer, tnx for your response, i will do it :)